# How do I format my very complicated work experience on my CV?

Tags: resume, work-experience

#### Company X

Company X develops a software product. They dont sell their product directly, but through partners. This is part of the company's own *Terms and Conditions*

#### Background story

As part of my education I started an internship at company A selling the product of company X.

3 months later the company changed name to B and 9 months later the company went bankrupt.

My manager (with assistance from company X) bought our customers and took a few employees (including me) to start a new company (company C).

8 months later, company X fires my manager (*he spend company money on private expenses*) and the company was taken over by company X.

Because company X won't sell their product directly they try to sell company C.

After 4 months with company X as my manager, we were sold to a new company D.

6 months later the company name (company C) was disbanded, and we were directly transfered to company D.

#### My question

I ended my internship and started as a full-time employee in the period where company C was owned by company X.

How should I format my work experience on LinkedIn / my CV?

**Edit**: For clarification I was doing the same work in the same role with the same customers and the same product through all companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is assuming that your job isn't related to mergers and acquisitions in which case it might actually be good to mention the company specifics.

You held the same job, but the company changed.  Being with such little experience as you have I would list your role and the final company name.  If you changed roles a few times you might want to call that out as you have experience in multiple roles, but as far as the company goes that says more about the company and not you so just list it all as working for the same company.

Think of it this way, if there was a product and it shifted hands 15 times would the product not be the product any longer?  It stays the product even though it gets re-branded and ownership changes.  You are essentially selling yourself on a resume, you didn't change a bunch of times, the placement of your work hierarchy changed.  Keep the resume focused on you and if there are questions you can relay the company shifting to answer questions while indicate you persisted through all the shifts...which shows your value cause you weren't axed along the way.

Comment: Very good! I came to the same conclussion - but I'm concerned that listing company D for 2 years will get me into trouble if somebody actually calls them and asks.

I've updated my question to make it clear to everyone that I was in the same role at all companies doing the same thing.

Comment: You can add a caveat that the company has changed hands 4 times, but you maintained your position throughout all transitions.